# Change Page in Frame Control

Tags: wpf, frame

I've got a Page in a Frame Control. I want to change it by clicking button in a current page. How can I do it?

I've got a full-screen desktop application on WPF (without any window's title and system buttons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use NavigationService.Navigate() method to navigate through pages in a Frame.

Comment: In that case I see a browser line on the top the page. It isn't look pretty :). Can I somehow get access to the parent Frame object from a page in it?

Comment: set ShowsNavigationUI="False" in the Page itself to hide that Navigation Bar.

Comment: It's a default value, however I tried to place this line of code to several places. It isn't working for me. What place should I put this line?

Comment: Thanks! You've given me a nudge. A Frame object has NavigationUIVisibiliy property. I've set it to "Hidden". The problem solved.